# Generating CSR on iPhone

Tags: iphone, security, csr

Could you tell me how can I generate CSR on iPhone with using Security.framework? Is it possible? I have looked through all manuals about Security but cannot find anything about it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: which security framework are you using ?

Comment: I'm trying to use only basic frameworks provided by Apple, because Apple does not recommend to use third-part frameworks for security features

Comment: Apple engineer told me that it is impossible to create CSR on iOS with using Security.framework and I should create ASN.1 structure manually or with using third-party tools. I found interesting solution http://lionet.info/asn1c/blog/ which helps create DER encoded files